# How to make a variable/constant available all the time once initialized?

Tags: java, swing, properties-file

I've a swing application that has to connect to database for some resources, for this i used `.properties` file to store database properties and that can be read at runtime.
For this i am using the following code

```
    public void readPropertiesFile(){
       try{
         InputStream is = ReadValues.class.getResourceAsStream(PROP_FILE);
         Properties prop = new Properties();
         prop.load(is);
         String URL = prop.getProperty("DB_URL");
         String user = prop.getProperty("DB_USER");
         String  pwd = prop.getProperty("DB_PWD");
         is.close();
      /* code to use values read from the file*/
       }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Failed to read from " + PROP_FILE + " file.");
       }
   }
```

but i've to call this method whenever i want to connect to the database (for `Connection` object).
I know the thing that now processing is fast enough to run these lines in micro seconds, but it's for my own knowledge that suggest me the ways through which i can store these DB values when application starts or the first time user try to connect to DB for any operation in such `objects` or `variables` or `constants` that will be usable until the application restarts and can be called directly without reading the file.

P.S. : I know that the DB values will not change oftentimes, and if it happens than i'll be happy to restart my application :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by making these static fields in a separate class, they will not be loaded until the first time you access URL,USER, or PASSWORD.

```
public class DbProps {
  public static final String URL;
  public static final String USER;
  public static final String PASSWORD;

  static {
       try{
         InputStream is = ReadValues.class.getResourceAsStream(PROP_FILE);
         try {
           Properties prop = new Properties();
           prop.load(is);
           URL = prop.getProperty("DB_URL");
           USER = prop.getProperty("DB_USER");
           PASSWORD = prop.getProperty("DB_PWD");
         } finally {
           is.close();
         }
       }catch(Exception e){
         throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read from " + PROP_FILE + " file.", e);
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have created a class `Constants` to hold all static constant values in application in which i'll stored these values when the class `DBProps` first initializes with start of application and then it will be utilized further..

Answer (score 2):

You can nake a check condition which will check if it is first time then set the value other wise use the existing value

```
public static boolean isFirstTime = true;
public static String URL = true;
public static String user = true;
public static String pwd = true;
public void readPropertiesFile(){
if(isFirstTime){
       try{

         InputStream is = ReadValues.class.getResourceAsStream(PROP_FILE);
         Properties prop = new Properties();
         prop.load(is);
         URL = prop.getProperty("DB_URL");
         user = prop.getProperty("DB_USER");
         pwd = prop.getProperty("DB_PWD");
isFirstTime = false;
         is.close();
      /* code to use values read from the file*/
       }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Failed to read from " + PROP_FILE + " file.");
       }
}
   }
//use this URL user and pwd in your application
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic environment class for you. You can get your DB props like `Environment.getEnvironment().getProperty("DB_URL")`, etc.

```
public class Environment {
   private static final String PROP_FILE = "somefilename";

   private static final Environment singleton = new Environment();

   public static Environment getEnvironment() {
      return singleton;
   }

   private Properties properties = new Properties();

   protected Environment() {
      super();
      loadProperties();
   }

   public Properties getProperties() {
      return properties;
   }

   public String getProperty(String propertyName) {
      return getProperty(propertyName, System.getProperty(propertyName));
   }

   public String getProperty(String propertyName, String defaultValue) {
      return getProperties().getProperty(propertyName, defaultValue);
   }

   public void loadProperties() {
      URL resourceURL = null;

      try {
         resourceURL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
               .getResource(PROP_FILE);
         getProperties().load(resourceURL.openStream());
         System.out.println("Loaded properties from "
               + resourceURL.toExternalForm());
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
         System.err.println("Failed to load properties from "
               + resourceURL.toExternalForm());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Same thing i am doing with `Constant` class of mine.. thanks for suggestion :)